# Setting flag column depending on whether column contains a given string

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

Can anyone see why this isn't working?

Its trying to do; if Column Name Contains the text 'Andy', then make a column called Andy and set that row = to 1

```
df.loc[df['Name'].str.contains(['Andy']),'Andy']=1
```

Comment: If you are planning to do this for other names then consider get_dummies method https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to remove list, need only string:

```
df.loc[df['Name'].str.contains('Andy'),'Andy'] = 1
```

For multiple values chain by `|`:

```
df.loc[df['Name'].str.contains('Andy|Andrew'),'Andy'] = 1
```

Answer (score 6):

[`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) requires for its `pat` argument a "Character sequence or regular expression", *not* a list.

Just use Boolean assignment and convert to `int`. This will set unmatched rows to `0`. For example:

```
# Name includes 'Andy'
df['Andy'] = df['Name'].str.contains('Andy').astype(int)

# Name includes 'Andy' or 'Andrew'
df['Andy'] = df['Name'].str.contains('Andy|Andrew').astype(int)
```